# Кастомизация плагина Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть вот такой замечательный участок кода, который идет в плагине, как расширение для Visual Composer

```
add_shortcode( 'digital_portfolio_query', 'digital_portfolio_query_shortcode' );


if ( ! function_exists('digital_portfolio_query_shortcode') ) {

function digital_portfolio_query_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'uid'              => '',
    'posts_per_page'   => '',
    'extra_class'      => null,
    'enable_nav'       => 'false',
    'autoplay'         => 'false',
    'speed'            => '1000',
  'category'         => ''
  ), $atts ) );

  global $secretlab;

    $slick_params = array( 'class'      => $extra_class ? $extra_class : 'digital_portfolios_box',
           'enable_nav' => $enable_nav,
           'autoplay'   => $autoplay,
           'speed'      => $speed ? $speed : 5000,
           'dots'       => 'false',
           'arrows'     => 'true',
           'prevArrow'  => '<div class="slick-prev">prev</div>',
           'nextArrow'  => '<div class="slick-next">next</div>',
           'sp_row'     => 1,
           'sp_show'    => 1,
           'sp_scroll'  => 1);
    $secretlab['slick'][] = $slick_params;


  $result = new WP_query('post_type=portfolio&category_name='.$category.'&posts_per_page='.$posts_per_page);

  $output = '';

  //Output posts

  if ( $result->posts ) :

    add_action('wp_footer', 'theseo_add_slick_carousel');

    // Main wrapper div

  $output .= '
      <div class="slider-web slick-slider">';

  // Loop through posts
  foreach ( $result->posts as $post ) :

    // Post VARS
    $post_id          = $post->ID;

      $short_post = types_render_field("short-description", array("post_id" => $post_id, "output"=>"normal"));
      $photo = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'large' );
      $link = get_permalink($post_id);
      // Portfolio post article start

      // Open details div
      $output .= '<div>
        <div class="post-slider">
          <div class="poster">
            '.$photo.'
          </div>
          <h3>'.$post->post_title.'</h3>
          <p>'.$short_post.'</p>
        </div>
      </div>';


    // End foreach loop
    endforeach;

    $output .= '
         </div>';


  endif; // End has posts check



  // Set things back to normal
  $result = null;
  wp_reset_postdata();

  // Return output
  return $output;

}

}
```

Он позволяет настроить выборку постов из Post Type - Portfolio

Вся проблема в том, что когда он делает эту выборку, то не видит постов, потому что в параметрах указано `category_name`, а не `taxonomy_name`

`$result = new WP_query('post_type=portfolio&category_name='.$category.'&posts_per_page='.$posts_per_page);`

Как через functions.php решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перекройте шорткод в плагине своим. Поскольку файлы темы загружаются после плагинов, можно просто переопределить шорткод своей функцией.

Вставьте в function.php

```
add_shortcode( 'digital_portfolio_query', 'my_digital_portfolio_query_shortcode' );

function my_digital_portfolio_query_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
  // здесь модифицированный код digital_portfolio_query_shortcode
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, я просто скопировал код в свой functions.php и в нем поменял параметры выборки и все good